# Fuzzy Screen Shots

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a screenshot of a coding window to a website, when I make the image smaller, the writing becomes distorted and unreadable.

Is there any way around this? In terms of how to create the screen shot or how to display it?

I created a JSFiddle with a random example to try and demonstrate my problem, I want three screenshots to fit side by side, yet still be clear and readable.

```
<img class="screen-example" style="height:200px; width:400px;" src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAKPAAAAJDA2Y2U1Y2EwLTYzMzItNGM2OS04ZjU3LTQzMTk0MDhkMDk1NA.jpg">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ccokdwbv/

Comment: Take smaller screenshots…? Naturally you're physically unable to fit as much visual information into a small image as you can into a large image.

Comment: Fit 5 people on a bike and yet be comfortable?

Comment: @Jones [Bad analogy.](https://agrandloveaffairwithadventure.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/overloaded-motorbike.jpg) ;-)

Comment: `XD` @deceze nooo not comfortale `:P`

Comment: @Chris would a possible solution be to use `<pre>` code blocks to show your code instead of screenshots?

Comment: @Jalen Davenport, that is an interesting thought. I am more of a back end developer so I have not heard of that, I will have a research and see what I can come up with. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris here is a really simple example of what I am talking about: http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weekfour/code-test.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something that you can do with your example, you have scaled your images too small to be readable. Here is a quick explanation: Say your screen shot is originally 1000px wide, and has text, and if you look really closely at your screen you can see that letters are about 8 pixels wide. That means there are 8 tiny little dots in width to show the curve of an 'R' or the zigzag in a 'Z'. Think about pixel art, or trying to spell out letters using little tiles.

Now when you scale your image down in width, to say 200px wide, your computer's pixels are still the same size, but now instead of having 8 pixels to convey a letter, you only have 2 pixels - as a result the image becomes distorted. You can't cram anything extra into a pixel, that's it, it's just one dot of color.

Comment: Thank you, this is something I did not think about or know. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use bootstrap classes to make your image responsive.Also for fitting 3 images in a row, you can use bootstrap "row" class and divide the screen into three columns.Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><img src=" "/></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><img src=" "/></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><img src=" "/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Making images "responsive" still means that you are scaling down a bunch of pixels … which makes the content unreadable … which is the problem being asked about.